# Does Visual Studio Code have Performance Profiling Tools for C#?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio-code, profiling, game-development

I'm making a video game with the MonoGame framework that uses the C# language. I'm looking into optimizing my code to run better on slower machines and I'm wondering if there's a way I can diagnose slow parts of my code using Visual Studio Code.

I'm aware that Visual Studio Community has performance diagnosis tools, but I usually avoid purple vs code because it makes me angry whenever I use it.

If there are other alternatives too I wouldn't mind knowing about them, but having something in VS Code would be pretty neat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While Visual Studio Code lacks the built-in performance diagnosis features found in Visual Studio Community, there are alternative approaches you can take. To diagnose performance issues in your C# project, you can make use of the [`.NET Trace` tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace). This tool can be utilized from the command line.